Laravel backpack overwrite update blade file for just one CRUD
I am trying to hide 'edit' button from a trashed item just one CRUD, Copied update blade file into resources/views/vendor/backpack/crud/buttons/ and updated the first line
@if ($crud->hasAccess('update', $entry) && !$entry->trashed())

Is it possible to load the update blade with conditon(!$entry->trashed()) just one controller?
None of the other models has 'deleted_at' column.
laravel: 8.x
Backpack: 5.x

Did you try reading the entity name like
$crud->entity_name

And with this decide the operation or filters to apply.
Cheers.

There are multiple ways to get the desired results.
For me the easiest one would be to set the access conditions without overwriting any file.
Backpack has a fairly simple but powerful access control system: https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/6.x/crud-cheat-sheet#all-operations
I would just add in my setup() method for that particular controller:
CRUD::setAccessCondition(['update'], function ($entry) {
    return ! $entry->trashed();
});

And .. that's it, it should work as expected.
In case it doesn't feel free to open an issue in our community forum: https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/community-forum/discussions/ and we can help you to sort it out.
Cheers

Create a copy of the button and customize it (call it update_trashed or something different than the original update name so it does not overwrite the original button in other Controllers) then modify the button that the UpdateOperation adds:
protected function setupListOperation()
{
    // ... your columns, filters etc

    CRUD::modifyButton('update', ['content' => 
    'crud::buttons.update_trashed']); 
    // you can place the new button wherever you want, as long as you provide 
      the proper view path here. 
}

